# Eclipse won't allow me to return a String and insists on return null, what can I change please?

Tags: string, if-statement, null, return

Need to translate a star cartoon into a program. For the numeric ratings
given i.e. 1.0, 3.5 etc it should return a textual interpretation as in 
"OK" or "excellent" and otherwise "not rated". Eclipse won't let me compile without asking for return null and I am stuck, Thank you for help!

```
public class StarRating { 

public static String interpret (double rating) {
         if ( rating <= 3.5 )  {
            System.out.println ("crap"); 
        }
        else if (rating == 4.0) {
            System.out.println   ("OK");
        }
        else if (rating == 4.5){
        System.out.println ("excellent");
        }
        else if (rating == 5.0){
        System.out.println ("[has only one review]");
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("not rated");
         return null; //eclipse won't compile without return null
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since interpret is declared `public static String interpret(double)`, it must return a String.  Without the `return null`, you are just printing a String (using `System.out.println`), and the program won't compile without returning a value.  You have two options:

- Change the definition of interpret to `public static void interpret(double)` and don't return anything
- Switch to returning the strings for each rating rather than printing them, so `return "crap"` rather than `System.out.println("crap")`

Comment: Yes thats it Alec, I got rid of the System.outprintln and it no longer asked for return null, and then compiled no problem, thank you!